# How to formulate this problem when analysing "choose up to X items" survey results

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference

I have these survey results that came from the marketing team in my company. The survey has a few questions that you can choose up to 3 or 5 items from a list. I don't know the name of this kind of question and would be delighted to know more.

We plotted the results in a bar chart and it is clear to me that some of the items in the list are favorites and some are not. But there is a bulk of items that might be in a zone that is not very clear to me that they are "statistically significant" - if that is a thing in these kinds of surveys.

In my current formulation, an item would map to a feature or feature set that we would have to develop and therefore is associated with a return. I'm assuming the return is a function of the number of users who picked that particular item. For the sake of simplicity and clarity in my formulation, I'm supposing it is proportional to the number of people who chose that item.

What I'm trying to understand is what would be a good way to determine items that are estimated to have above-average returns - again, in a "statistically significant" sense - much like a one-armed bandit problem. I'm trying to learn more about surveys in general, and I wanted to clarify how any of you would better formulate the analysis of this survey or if there is any particular test or statistic that you would use to analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a formulation that works for this particular problem I was looking at. The idea is to see the problem as a ranking problem rather than a bandit one and therefore find a reasonable way to rank it.

One particular ranking method and analysis I found to be of interest was the [Pareto analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_analysis) that I've seen in a [Food Science video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYdHVmCd5Mc). You rank the items by the frequency they appeared in the survey and cap the analysis to the top N or top 80% in cumulative sum to see what are the most impactful traits of a product.

The video even goes on to talk about either copying the traits of a successful product or finding underserved traits. Very interesting ideas.